# How can I add picture as a JButton background?

Tags: java, icons, jbutton

I'm trying to add an image to JButton so there will be some kind of icon. And I'm not sure where is my mistake. When I run the following code, there is no changes in how button looks.

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("img.bmp");
JButton button = new JButton(img);
frame.add(button);
```

I've already tried to debug my code, although there was nothing useful.

Comment: Try to load the image manually, e.g. via `ImageIO.read(…)`. This way, you get a feedback on errors. Then, just use the [`ImageIcon` constructor accepting an `Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.awt.Image))

Answer (score 0):

Where is img.bmp stored relative to the
"working directory"?
ImageIcon (String) expects to find a
file on the disk, in this case, in the root of
the "working directory". If you don't know
the working directory, add
System. out.println(System.getPro
perty("user.dir")); to your code,
the image you're trying to load should be
stored there. The problem with this though,
is the working directory can change. You'd
be better of using embedded resources

Comment: Great explaination. It would be great if your answer could be bit more concise. You can use bullet points instead to highlight your main points. Also use special formatting for writing code snippets to increase readability of your submission.